# Have I written a generic method?

Tags: java, generics

```
submitButton.setOnAction(e -> totalPrice(Double.parseDouble(inputText.getText()), spinner.getValue()));
```

The above statement runs the method below. Retrieves a numerical value that was entered in the gui input window, and whatever number the user set the spinner to.

```
public <E extends Number> void totalPrice(E input, E quantity)
{
    String doubleToString = String.format("$%.2f", input.doubleValue() * quantity.doubleValue());

    outputText.setText(doubleToString);
}
```

The above method takes the inputs of the action and turns it into a string. outputText, which is the textfield that displays the result in the gui, is set as the string. And it works.

My question is actually very simple.

Did i write a real generic? The assignment specified that a generic must be used, and the first time around, my code worked but I quickly realized no generic was used. I think i got it the second time around but i could be very wrong. Are there changes i need to make? Any poor code?

Comment: Yes, you wrote a real generic. Congratulations!

Comment: Well, it's real in the sense that the syntax is correct.  You might want to ask your instructor if this is indeed what was requested.  Since you can trivially replace `E` with just `Number` I don't feel its a great example.

Comment: @markspace Can you elaborate? I did attempt to change the E's to Number, but it led to errors inside the method as the .doubleValue() no longer worked and i could not multiply input by quantity.

Comment: It's a generic method nothing to worry about...

Comment: You must have done it wrong.  `Number` defines `doubleValue()`, it must be something else. (We're talking `java.lang.Number`, right?)

Comment: @markspace [picture of code](https://i.imgur.com/WaY1OFc.png)
I'm not sure what exactly you mean by replacing with Number. Are you saying I should replace everything or only the two E's in the parameters? And why? What does it do for my code? I'd assume it could be beneficial since you've mentioned it.

Comment: @Lumi No, no, what he meant is that you don't need a generic method to do what you  did, remove <Number> from the code you linked and it will work in the same way as your original code.

Comment: @Oleg Oh wow, yeah I see now. So is the instructor requiring us to use generics kind of pointless in this specific scenario? Or am I missing something?

Comment: As far as I can see, yes, this is totally pointless.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Others already answered the question in their comments; just to give you a bit more explanation why this is a generic method.

As you are not sure if the method is generics, here is a definition for generics (an extract from the [Java Language Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.4)):

> A method is generic if it declares one or more type variables (§4.4).
>
> These type variables are known as the type parameters of the method. The form of the type parameter section of a generic method is identical to the type parameter section of a generic class (§8.1.2).
>
> A generic method declaration defines a set of methods, one for each possible invocation of the type parameter section by type arguments. Type arguments may not need to be provided explicitly when a generic method is invoked, as they can often be inferred (§18 (Type Inference)).

The `type parameter` here is  `E` which is representing all possible types of numbers (short, int, long, float, double, ...). If you had to implement the requirement without generics you would have written lots of methods (therefore `set of methods`) with these different parameters. Now you have only one generic method which is accepting all possible numbers as parameters.

Here is also the official [Java Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) on generic methods.

Even though it is not clear from the requirement, I would modifiy the method as follows:

```
public <E extends Number> void totalPrice(E input, int quantity) {
    String doubleToString = String.format("$%.2f", input.doubleValue() * quantity);
    outputText.setText(doubleToString);
}
```

As you could see, I changed the second param from `E` to `int`. The reason is that it doesn't make sense the `quantity` to be other than int. But you can leave it as `E` (because of: *whatever number the user set the spinner to*)

So, as others already mentioned in their comments, this is syntactically valid generic method.